# Dynamic drop downs breaking after clone

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a table with a single row that has 2 drop downs. The second drop down is dependent on the first one via JQuery change event. Underneath my table I have a button that allows the user to clone a new table row and appends after my last row.

Now let's say I have clicked my button and I now have 2 rows. When I make a selection on the first row, first drop down the second drop down on the first row becomes available and I can make a selection.

When I change the second row first drop down, the second drop down in the first row changes accordingly to the selection I had made in my second row first drop down.

Here is what my HTML looks like

```
<table id="component_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Component</th>
            <th>Component Type</th>
            <th>Component Thickness</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="component_tb">
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $roofComponentDropDown ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $roofComponentTypeDropDown ?></td> 
            <td><input id="component_thickness" name="component_thickness" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" value="+" id="addRows" />
```

And here is each drop down

```
$roofComponentQuery = "SELECT * FROM roof_component";
$roofComponentData = mysqli_query($dbc, $roofComponentQuery);

while ($rcRow = mysqli_fetch_array($roofComponentData)) {
         $roofComponentOptions .="<option value=\"".$rcRow['roof_component_id']."\">" . $rcRow['roof_component_name'] . "</option>";
}

$roofComponentDropDown = "<select name='selectedRoofComponent' id='selectedRoofComponent' onChange='getComponentType(this.value)'>
                            <option selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select Component</option>
                        " . $roofComponentOptions . "
                        </select></br>";

$roofComponentTypeDropDown = "<select name='selectedComponentType' id='selectedComponentType'>
                                <option class='toggle_control' selected='selected' disabled='disabled' value=''>Select Type</option>
                            </select></br>";
```

Here is my change event for the drop down.

```
function getComponentType(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getroofcomponenttype.php",
    data:'roof_component_id='+val,

    success: function(data){
            $("#selectedComponentType").html(data);
    }
    });
}
```

This is how I am cloning the table row when the user clicks my `+` button

```
$(function() {
    var $componentTB = $("#component_tb"),
        $firstTRCopy = $componentTB.children('tr').first().clone();
    $("#addRows").click(function() {
        $componentTB.append($firstTRCopy.clone());
    });
});
```

I know currently that with this cloning function I am duplicating ID's which is bad [(working on it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419392/how-to-clone-and-append-a-table-row/29429565#29429565).

I am not sure what to do here, How can I make it so that each table row drop downs are dependent with only drop downs in that row?

I am going to eventually have to iterate through this table and insert each tables selected information into a MySQL DB.

Should I be doing this some other way?

Please any help would be great.

Comment: "The second drop down is dependent on the second one"?  Please clarify.

Comment: It was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing only the value, pass the whole element. Replace `onChange='getComponentType(this.value)'` with `onChange='getComponentType(this)'` in your PHP code.
And your ajax call should be:

```
function getComponentType(ele) {
    var ths = $(ele);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getroofcomponenttype.php",
        data:'roof_component_id='+ths.val(),
        success: function(data){
            ths.parent().parent().find("#selectedComponentType").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The third code block is how I am linking up the drop downs.

Comment: @BigRabbit Sorry i didnt get it the first time. Please see my updated answer.